# Determine the generalized eigenspace of A

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, generalized-eigenvector

I have this exercise, which I am having some problems with. It says, let $\alpha,\beta$ be scalars in a field characteristic $\neq 2$, and let $A\in$ End(V) be the linear transformation of $V=\mathcal{F}^3$ which is represented by:

$$[A]=\begin{pmatrix}
0&\alpha&1\\
0&1&0 \\
1&\beta&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

with respect to the standard basis. Determine the generalized eigenspaces of A, for every $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from $\mathcal{F}$.

I've started by finding the eigenvalues for A, by solving finding the characteristic polynomial for $A-\lambda I$ to be $(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-1)$, and then solving $(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-1)=0$, and then I found $\lambda=\pm 1$. Where $\lambda=1$ has multiplicity 2, and $\lambda=-1$ has multiplicity 1.

To find the generalized eigenvectors I have to solve $(A-\lambda I)^k x=0$. Since $\lambda=1$ has multiplicity 2, I have $(A-\lambda I)^k x=0$ for k=2, so I determined:

$(A-\lambda I)^2= \begin{pmatrix}
-1&\alpha&1\\
0&0&0\\
1&\beta&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}
2&\alpha-\beta&-2\\
0&0&0\\
-2&\alpha-\beta&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

So to determine the generalized eigenvectors, I have to solve:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&\alpha-\beta&-2\\
0&0&0\\
-2&\alpha-\beta&2\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

So, I have to solve:

$$2x_1+(\alpha-\beta)x_2-2x_3=0$$

$$-2x_1+(\alpha-\beta)x_2+2x_3=0$$

And that's what I don't really know how to do.

And I have the same problem for $\lambda = -1$, where I have:

$$A-\lambda I=\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda&\alpha&1\\
0&1-\lambda&0\\
1&\beta&-\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

So here, I have to solve:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&\alpha&1\\
0&2&0\\
1&\beta&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}=0
$$

So I have to solve:

$$x_1+\alpha x_2+x_3=0$$
$$2x_2=0$$
$$x_1+\beta x_2+x_3=0$$

And that's what I don't get how to do, so I'd appreciate some help

Comment: I suggest wording this as looking for the minimal polynomial.  The characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda - 1)^2 ( \lambda + 1).$ The minimal polynomial is either that or $(\lambda -1) (\lambda + 1).$  The simple thing to check is $(A-I)(A+I).$ If this is zero for an $(\alpha, \beta)$ pair, then $A$ diagonalizes. If not, you get a nontrivial Jordan form. That is, the exponent for an eigenvalue factor in the characterisic polynomial is always the size of the largest Jordan block

Comment: I don't get how that would help me solving this?

Comment: you write "So here, I have to solve"  near the end, but you do not need to do that at all. Find out the minimal polynomial. Have you ever heard of Jordan Canonical Form or Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: No I have never hear of that